# UITableView set background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I change the background color of the UITableViewCells in the *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath* method

```
    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor = ...
    } else{
        cell.backgroundColor = ...
    }
```

But that only change the color of the cell amount specified in *tableView:numberOfRowsInSection* (As seen in the attached picture, there are white cells after the first four)

Is it possible to change the color of all cells that are displayed on screen?

[image]

Comment: But why are you displaying empty row??

Comment: I think thats the default behavior of the tableview to display as many rows as the height of the screen? and it looks kind of strange if only a few datasets are displayed to the user, so the empty ones are white.

Comment: If you add an empty footer view, then the extra rows will disappear and give you one solid colour for the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want the cell background color to continue to alternate, then you need to lie about how many rows are in the table. Specifically, in *tableView:numberOfRowsInSection* you need to always return a number that will fill the screen, and in *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath*, return a blank cell for rows that are beyond the end of the table.  The following code demonstrates how to do this, assuming that *self.dataArray* is an NSArray of NSStrings.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ( self.dataArray.count < 10 )
        return( 10 );
    else
        return( self.dataArray.count );
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];

    if ( indexPath.row % 2 == 0 )
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    else
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    if ( indexPath.row < self.dataArray.count )
        cell.textLabel.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    else
        cell.textLabel.text = nil;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 42):

1. Open Storyboard
2. Select your UITableView
3. Open Attribute inspector
4. Scroll to View group
5. Select background color for entire table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks way better right now. But could I also achieve the same style as the table (different colors for odd and even cells) or is this not possible by default?

Comment: So something like providing a custom view as the background view of the UITableView?

Comment: To manage tableview's background you can work with `self.tableView.backgroundView.layer`. Here is a good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/calayers-tutorial-for-ios-introduction-to-calayers-tutorial

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using the solution suggested by user3386109. But CALayers are really interesting. They helped me to solve an other problem I had (add a drop-shadow to the header of the section in the TableView).

Comment: This does not work for me. Did this on a cell by cell basis in cellForRowAtIndexPath as per user3386109. Maybe the table is covered by all of its cells or something like that, so I am never seeing the actual table background. Not sure what the case is where this works

Answer (score 12):

Try like this:-

```
self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift, you can change tableview background color or you can set image to tableview background color like this;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}


//    change cell text color and background color
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this to color alternate cell in a table view

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        }
        else
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the tableview's `backgroundView` to `nil` and its `backgroundColor` to the desired color.

Answer (score 1):

**For SWIFT**

Thanks to @Irshad Qureshi I was able to get alternating background colors for my prototype cells by adding the following in my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
    {
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
    }
    else
    {
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```

Comment: Welcome Brother

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 and up

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Set Clear Backcolor
    //cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    //or in your case
    if ( indexPath.row % 2 == 0 )
        cell.backgroundColor = .orange
    else
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
}
```