# How to set the UITableView background color programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I created UITableView programmatically.I want to change the UITableView background color as below.Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView set background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743184/uitableview-set-background-color)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift**

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Take the RGB value and do the need full

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 16.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

**Objective C**

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Thanks alot.Please can you guide me how to set the exact RGB color programmatically

Comment: Your color values according to color picker is

[UIColor colorWithRed:0.827f green:0.780f blue:0.824f alpha:1.00f]

.You also have to make the background color of each cell the same
in order to achieve the screen which you have posted

 
  .cell.backgroundColor = 
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.827f green:0.780f blue:0.824f alpha:1.00f];

Or you can just clear the backgroundcolor of cell

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your code

```
self.YourTableName.backgroundColor = [UIColor PurpleColor];
self.YourTableName.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

And

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Correct the typo in ClearColor..
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: nice and easy. like that.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set tableView backgroundColor will change all tableView's color, but tableView is covered by cell. so you can't see it. if you want to see the change, you can set cell.contentView.backgroundColor.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: your RGB is [UIColor colorWithRed:211.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:210.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];