# Divide UitableViewCell into two colours

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to make my table view cell like progress bar . How much progress is done according to that cell's background colour should change . I am not able to do that in UITableViewCell .

**Edit**

Its not about changing the colour of the alternative cells . Its about two applying two colours into same cell.

Comment: You can use a custom `UITableViewCell` with a view to be adapted according to the progress.

Comment: @Larme , yes I can do that but its like how to use directly while configuring the cell .

Comment: Change the cell backgroundColor based on your progreess.

Comment: Add one UIView or Label as sub view of cell content view and give width as per the progress and set differnt background colour to cell and View(UILable /UIView)

Comment: @VineeshTP , Its not about changing the background colour , Its the width of the background colour .

Comment: @Bindi: check the cell content view color also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView set background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743184/uitableview-set-background-color)

Comment: @VibhaSingh , That may be the last option I have .

Comment: If you want two colours in the same cell, set in your customCell 2 UIViews with diferents backgroundColours, not? One view above other. 50 - 50

Comment: @Patrick , by adding a view programatically it is done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make custom tableview cell class. Add view with 0 or 1 width and required height to cell from interfacebuider to cell's content view or if want to add programmatically then add that view from `awakeFromNib` of custom cell class method.

Then set desired background color of that view and add increase it's width as per progress.

If there is no specific progress then you can add animation with some duration to increase it's width.

If you are using autolayout then manipulate constraint's outlet to increase width, if not using autolayout then manipulate view's frame to increase width.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Yes , I have done using adding a view programmatically ,  It overlaid my cell ' s labels .  But decreasing the alpha it is achieved .

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     static NSString *temp= @"CustomCell";
     CustomCell *cellheader = (CustomCell *)[tableViewObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:temp];
     // add your if condition
     cellheader.contentView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:72.0/255.0 green:72.0/255.0 blue:72.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
 }
```